# Activating Vertices and Edges selecting modes simultaneously

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

How can i convert from Edges to Vertices selection, in my modeling? I need to keep Edges and Vertices selected, not to switch selection from Edges to Vertices.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 3D View, you can change your selection mode by clicking the related buttons (check the image) you can activate 1 selection mode, or 2 by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> and clicking the related button, or you can activate all of them using the same method, so you can activate Vertices, Edges and Faces selection modes at the same time.
In the image you can see I have both Vertices and Edges selection modes activated.
[image]

Comment: It converted my selection. Thanks, it works

Answer (score 2):

While the information Georges provided is correct, there is an alternate method that I sometimes find useful, the hotkey combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>. This opens a dialog box in which one can select vertex, edge, or face mode, though not more than one mode at the same time.